# Как присвоить значение переменной из свойства объекта в Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

В строке `/*1*/` объявляю переменную `identifier`.

В строке `/*2*/` пытаюсь присвоить ей значение из `notification.request.identifier`.

В строке `/*3*/` переменная `identifier` имеет значение `nil`.

Что я делаю не так и как сделать правильно? К сожалению почти впервые вижу Objective-C.

В строке `/*2*/` `notification.request.identifier` точно имеет значение отличное от `nil`;

```
if([UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] != nil){
      
/*1*/ __block NSString *identifier; 
      
      [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotification *> * _Nonnull notifications) {
        for (UNNotification *notification in notifications) {
          if ([notification.request.content.userInfo[@"id"] isEqualToString:notificationId]) {
/*2*/        identifier = notification.request.identifier;
          }
        }
      }];
      
/*3*/ if (identifier != nil) {
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers:@[identifier]];
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler:` выполняется асинхронно, поэтому строка 3 выполняется раньше, чем 2. Поэтому ваш код можно переписать так (я еще убрал ненужные проверки на `nil`)

```
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotification *> * _Nonnull notifications) {
        for (UNNotification *notification in notifications) {
            if ([notification.request.content.userInfo[@"id"] isEqualToString:notificationId]) {
                /*2*/
                NSString *identifier = notification.request.identifier;
                /*3*/
                [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers:@[identifier]];
                break;
            }
        }
    }];
```

Comment: В итоге так и переписал, спасибо за пояснения.